# Pyspark calculate a field on a grouped table

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a data frame that looks like this:

```
+-------+-----+-------------+------------+
|startID|endID|trip_distance|total_amount|
+-------+-----+-------------+------------+
|      1|    3|            5|          12|
|      1|    3|            0|           4|
+-------+-----+-------------+------------+
```

I need to create a new table that groups the trips by the start and end IDs, and then figures out what the average trip rate was.

The trip rate is figured by taking all the trips with the same start and end IDs, in my case `startID` 1, and `endID` 3, had a total of 2 trips, and for those 2 trips the avg `trip_distance` was 2.5, and avg `total_amount` was 8. So the `trip_rate` should be 8/2.5=3.2

So the end result should look like this:

```
+-------+-----+-----+----------+
|startID|endID|count| trip_rate|
+-------+-----+-----+----------+
|      1|    3|    2|       3.2|
+-------+-----+-----+----------+
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 3, 5, 12),
        (1, 3, 0, 4)
    ],
    ['startID', 'endID', 'trip_distance', 'total_amount'] # add your columns label here
)
df.show()
grouped_table = df.groupBy('startID', 'endID').count().alias('count')
grouped_table.show()

grouped_table = df.withColumn('trip_rate', (avg('total_amount') / avg('trip_distance')))
grouped_table.show()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`startID`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '((avg(`total_amount`) / avg(`trip_distance`)) AS `trip_rate`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`startID`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;\nAggregate [startID#0L, endID#1L, trip_distance#2L, total_amount#3L, (avg(total_amount#3L) / avg(trip_distance#2L)) AS trip_rate#44]\n+- LogicalRDD [startID#0L, endID#1L, trip_distance#2L, total_amount#3L], false\n"
```

I tried wrapping the calculation in an AS function, but I kept getting syntax errors.

Comment: Why do you divide 8 by `3`? Shouldn't it be `8/2.5=3.2` ? Or are you rounding off 2.5

Comment: You were right, it should have been 3.2. I updated the question in case someone else stumbles on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by, sum and divide. `count` and `sum` can be used inside `agg()`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy('startID', 'endID').agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("count"), \
    (F.sum("total_amount")/F.sum("trip_distance")).alias('trip_rate')).show()
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!!